# Updating values in a table if present in a different table using pandas merge

Tags: pandas, merge

I have 2 tables, Table p and Table q. The contents of Table p are to be updated from Table q.

Table p:

```
     A    B    C
1   45   22   25
2   34   46   56
3   59   55   44
```

Table q:

```
     A    B   C 
1   34   46   59
2   59   55   49
```

I want to merge these two tables based on column 'A' and 'B' such that if values of 'A', 'B' in table p are not present in table q, values in column B in table p are the same.

Tried:

```
p['A'] = pd.merge(q, on=['A','B'], how='left')['C']
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C
1   45    22  NaN   
2   34    46   59 
3   59    55   49
```

Desired Output:

```
     A    B    C
1   45    22   25
2   34    59   59
3   59    55   49
```

I can create a different column and merge and then combine back to column 'A' of table p but that seems lengthy. Is there a more direct way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can using `update`

```
keycol=['A','B']
df1=df1.set_index(keycol)
df1.update(df2.set_index(keycol))
df1
Out[762]: 
          C
A  B       
45 22  25.0
34 46  59.0
59 55  49.0
df1.reset_index()
Out[763]: 
    A   B     C
0  45  22  25.0
1  34  46  59.0
2  59  55  49.0
```

Another solution from `map`

```
df1.A.map(df2.set_index('A').B).fillna(df1.B)
Out[727]: 
1    22.0
2    59.0
3    99.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Comment: What if I had many sets of columns (not just A)  that I had to lookup for updating?

Comment: @pnkjmndhl in this case , set them all to the index df1=df1.set_index([your columns list ])

Comment: How do you use map if you had to look many columns from df1 and df2?

Comment: @pnkjmndhl this solution is only working for your sample , not for real , just post it for future visitors

Comment: I have slightly changed the question, could you please update your answer?

Comment: This was supposed to be the actual question, I tried to simplify it before posting it. I guess I oversimplified it.